# Parsing Json with more than one inner array in it in android

Tags: android, json

I want to draw a graph using periods and values any one have any Idea about getting these inner arrays as an array list?how to parse these inner arrays to array list?

Here is the json:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "success": true,
    "message": "Food consumed graph result",
    "periods": {
        "0": "Anytime",
        "1": "Breakfast",
        "2": "Morning Snack",
        "3": "Lunch",
        "4": "Afternoon Snack",
        "5": "Dinner"
    },
    "values": {
        "0": 0,
        "1": 0,
        "2": 0,
        "3": 0,
        "4": 0,
        "5": 0
    },
    "chartTitle": "Calorie intake over today",
    "xTitle": "periods",
    "yTitle": "calories",
    "tooltipText": "Calorie consumed",
    "tooltipUnit": "cal"
}
```

Comment: there is no array. also post what you have tried

Comment: use gson : http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: If you are talking about `{"0":0,"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":0}` - it's not an array from JSON point of view. In JSON you typically use something like `[0,1,2,0,0]` to store such data.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below:

```
    JSONObject vals = jsonObj.getJSONObject("values");
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    Iterator iter = vals.keys();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
      String key = (String)iter.next();
      String value = vals.getString(key);
      map.put(key,value);
    }
```